# Differentiate a block from an object initializer

Tags: javascript, syntax, grammar, ecmascript-5

This is more a theoretical question than a practical one. It's about the parsing of some code delimited by curly braces.

Here are two examples of [object initializers](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5) :

```
f({});
({a:3})
```

Here are two examples of [blocks](http://es5.github.io/#x12.1) :

```
;{}
{a:3;}
```

In practice, it seems that `{...}` makes a block apart if the precedent code requires an expression.

But I've never seen such a rule explicit or made obvious in the ECMAScript specification and I'm not even sure it's true.

Is there a definitive non ambiguous reference somewhere ? A correct rule if this one isn't ?

Comment: `ExpressionStatement: [lookahead ∉ {{, function}] Expression;`

Comment: @Bergi Can you be more explicit for a poor coder just back from holidays and whose coffee didn't yet kick in.

Comment: An expression statement must not begin with a curly brace, therefore a "statement delimited by curly braces" is always a block. All other curly braces are no statements, but expressions - object initialisers.

Comment: @dystroy ({}) is an expression. that's why you wrap json with `()` /when dealing with eval

Comment: (merely related info) eval is for JavaScript expression, statement, or sequence of statements..but sometimes we need to make it parse as expressions. e.g. when we get json like '{"employees":"John"}'  , we need to make sure it wont be used as a statement(which will cause an error   , cause it thinks (as a statement) that it is a block of code but statement can't go along with object literals "employees".So we wrap it with (..) and now it will be parsed an object and not as a statement.(which will cause an error). Example : `eval('{"a":"1"}')` //error. while `eval('({"a":"1"})')` is not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a definitive non ambiguous reference somewhere ?

It's sort of spread all over the spec.

The short answer:

It depends on the context where the construct appears (which is why it's all over the spec). Probably the most specific place it's addressed is [§12.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4), where it says that an *ExpressionStatement* (an expression used where a statement is expected) can't start with a `{`.

The long answer:

The key is what the parser is expecting when it encounters the `{`: If it's expecting a statement, then it knows the `{` begins a block. But if it's expecting an expression, then it knows the `{` begins an object initializer. Let's look at an assignment:

```
doThis();   // This line is just for context
x = {a: 3};
```

At the beginning of the second line above, the parser is expecting a statement. But then it sees the `x =` and knows it's handling an assignment; at that point, after seeing the `=`, the parser is expecting an *expression*. A *statement* is invalid there. So it knows the `{` starts an object initializer, not a block.

In contrast:

```
doThis();   // This line is just for context
{a: 3};
```

The second line above is a block containing a labelled statement. (A very odd-looking one; we'll come back to that.) The parser knows that because at the beginning of that line, the parser is expecting a statement, not an expression.

There are lots of other places where the parser expects to see expressions, not statements. For instance, after the `:` in a property initializer:

```
obj = {
    prop: {a: 3}
};
```

...or within the arguments when doing a function call:

```
foo({a: 3});
```

...or after a unary operator, or just after an opening `(`, etc. In the spec, you can tell what the parser will be expecting by what it says in the grammar for what the parser is parsing, e.g. this syntax diagram from [§12.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) defining the `if` statement:

```
 IfStatement :

    if ( Expression ) Statement else Statement

    if ( Expression ) Statement
```

That tells us that when handling an `if` statement, within the `()` the parser expects an expression, but after the `if ()` bit, it expects a statement.

So far so good, but JavaScript allows (almost) any expression wherever a statement is allowed. This is valid, for instance:

```
doThis();   // This line is just for context
flag && doThat();
```

The second line above is a binary logical operator expression, but freestanding. The parser was expecting a statement when it encountered it. So the `&&` expression is what the spec calls an *ExpressionStatement*. *ExpressionStatement* is defined by [§12.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4).

So that leaves us with some ambiguity: If the parser is expecting a statement, and sees a `{`, how does it know that's not the beginning of an object initializer expression acting as an *ExpressionStatement*?

The answer is: By fiat. :-) §12.4 says this when defining *ExpressionStatement*:

> NOTE An *ExpressionStatement* cannot start with an opening curly brace because that might make it ambiguous with a *Block*.

So there's no ambiguity, not because of some subtle syntax trick, but just because the spec says so. :-)

(If you had a reason for really, really wanting to use an object initializer expression as a statement, you can do it; just put it within `()`.)

Comment: If there is no comma like `{ a: b }`, how do you know if `a:` is a label or a righthand value?

Comment: They're not commas, they're semicolons. But they don't have any effect on the decision in any case. @Derek朕會功夫: From the context. Again: If a right-hand value is expected, it's an initializer. If not, it's a block.

Comment: @Miszy It's a semicolon - but that's not the point, since Javascript engines try to ignore semicolons anyway, so you can omit it. It's considered a block since it's not used in a right-hand statement, and has a syntax compatible with blocks. `{"a": 3}`, on the other hand, is an object.

Comment: @MaxArt: JavaScript engines don't "try to ignore semicolons".

Comment: @MaxArt *semicolon, of course. JavaScript engines do not ignore semicolons. What you are talking about is Automatic Semicolon Insertion - engines ADD semicolons where they are needed - quite the opposite.
The distinction between object and a block here is clear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - What do you mean by "right-hand value is expected"? The browser has to know if `a:` is a label or not in order to expect or not expect a right-hand value.

Comment: What is a "right-hand value"? The spec does not use such a term; an object literal is a "primary expression" which can also occur in/as a left-hand-side-expression.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: You're applying the rule too late: You apply it to the `{`, not the `a:`: Does the `{` appear where you're expecting a right-hand value? If so, it's the beginning of an object initializer; if not, it's the beginning of a block.

Comment: @Miszy That's what I meant, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Bergi: I define "right-hand value" in the answer. It's a common term. I also explain in the answer why there is no ambiguity around *ExpressionStatement* (it's by fiat).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Wait so you were saying that `{a: b}` is the right-hand value. But if you just put `{a: b}` in a separate line then does this make it a block? Also the spec does say "An ExpressionStatement cannot start with an opening curly brace" but the first thing inside the `{}` is not an `ExpressionStatement`...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: *"Wait so you were saying that {a: b} is the right-hand value."* No, I am not. Please read again. ***If*** it appears where a right-hand value is expected, then we know it's an object initializer. If it appears where a statement is expected, we know it's a block. The construct `{a: b}` on its own, without context, could be either.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Okay now I'm confused.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ah, I see your definition. However, it's wrong - object initializers can not only occur as the right hand side of an assignment or as a function argument; they are valid `LeftHandSideExpression`s. Example: `false && ({a:5}=3)` is completely valid.

Comment: @Bergi: That's only valid because the bit after the `&&` is never evaluated. Try `true && ({a:5}=3)` and you'll get `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. Object initializers cannot be left-hand sides.

Comment: @Bergi - I don't think assigning `3` to `{a:5}` is valid.

Comment: People are getting ***really*** hung up on the "right-hand value" thing. I think I'd best reword to get rid of it, it appears to be confusing people.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Derek: I meant its *syntactically* valid (not throwing a `SyntaxError`), not that it's meaningful when executed :-)

Comment: I've rewritten the answer to get rid of the term people were getting hung up on.

Comment: In a line - This is just the difference between an ExpressionStatement and other types of expression.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, that's what Bergi was pointing (in a comment that wasn't detailed enough to be immediately clear in my opinion) and that's what was missing in my head.