# Why is { a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 } valid and { a: 1 } = { b: 2 } a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript

I do not understand why these two JS expressions are not equivalent

In order to get better at JS, I am experimenting with some javascript expressions. Here is my latest discovery:

```js
{ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 } // {b: 2}
{ a: 1     } = { b: 2 } // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Could anyone help me understand that?

Comment: `{ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }` -  SyntaxError: expected expression, got '=' - so, it's **NOT** valid

Comment: @JaromandaX: It does not throw in V8 console though (and indeed evaluates to `{b: 2}`)

Comment: The first is no more valid than the second

Comment: `{ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }` this is an error already, and it's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you destructuring? Are you missing a variable declaration (let/const/var) ? you are using a label `a` to create a global `y` variable `{a: y = 1}; console.log(y)` and assigning such block-scope to an object, which makes indeed no sense

Comment: `It does not throw in V8 console` ... V8 is broken ... `var { a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }` is legit, but without `var` it isn't

Comment: @JaromandaX: You are right (and Esprima agrees with you), but I can't understand that either. Why is `var { a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }` legit, and what does it parse to?

Comment: it parses to what it is ... you mean in "old" javascript? `var _b = {
  b: 2
},
    _b$a = _b.a,
    y = _b$a === void 0 ? 1 : _b$a;`

Comment: @JaromandaX Ooh, I seem to have skipped the default value syntax on destructuring. Learned something new. Thanks!

Comment: `Learned something new` - I strive to do so every day. That's how you become a good programmer

Comment: Throws error for both the syntax on firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, that is not the correct syntax for [destructuring assignments without declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration).

> The parentheses ( ... ) around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2} is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the {a, b} on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.

You can write one of the following:

```
// assignment with declaration
const { a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }
const { a: 1     } = { b: 2 }

// without declaration
({ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 })
({ a: 1     } = { b: 2 })
```

`const { a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }` will create a new variable `y` with value `1`. `a` cannot be [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from `{ b: 2 }`, but has a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2) of 1. `a` will also be [assigned to a new variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) name `y`.

`({ a: 1 } = { b: 2 })` won't work, because `a` cannot be destructured and has no default value. Hence, you get `SyntaxError: invalid destructuring target`.

#### Update - Some more background:

The [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Destructuring) is an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions). If you type `{ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }` in browser console, you'll get `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '='`, so the code cannot interpreted as an expression - instead it is considered a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) (zero or more statements). There is a solution - you can use parentheses to enforce an explicit expression context. That's the reason, why `({ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 })` works. You *can* also type `console.log({ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 })` in browser console, as the engine can be sure of the function argument to be an expression.

Also have a look at this [quote](https://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html):

> [...] with expression statements, there is an overlap: There, you have expressions that appear in a statement context. In order to prevent ambiguity, the JavaScript grammar forbids expression statements to start with a curly brace or with the keyword function.
>
> So what do you do if you want to write an expression statement that starts with either of those two tokens? You can put it in parentheses, which does not change its result, but ensures that it appears in an expression-only context.

#### Update 2 - Regarding browser/JavaScript engine differences

When you type `{ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }` in the console, you get following output:

- Firefox: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '='`
- Chrome and Node (both V8 engine):`{b: 2}`

Duh, why is that? The output from Chrome/Node is a sign that the code is indeed evaluated as expression by console, as it evaluates to the value `{b:2`} on the right side of the equality sign ([quote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions)):

> [...] conceptually, there are two types of expressions: with side effects (for example: those that assign value to a variable) and those that in some sense evaluate and therefore resolve to a value.
>
> The expression x = 7 is an example of the first type. This expression uses the = operator to assign the value seven to the variable x. The expression itself evaluates to seven.

If you type `eval('{ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }')` instead in Chrome/Node console, you'll get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='`, which is the correct behavior! `eval('var { a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }')` works as usual. I think, it's a strong sign, that the *console* itself actively tries to interpret the code as expression here and **V8 engine works properly** without a bug.

Comment: The question is about why the first one doesn't throw an error while the second does

Comment: OP isn't using `const { a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }`. OP is running `{ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }` in the browser's console. Assignment without declaration is done in both examples. Yet only one of them throws an error

Comment: There is more than one error in the sample: According to MDN, both expressions are invalid. Also the 2nd example has false destructuring target syntax. I think, it helps OP most, when both error causes are explained. Second error can only be triggered, if the first (missing parentheses) one is addressed.

Comment: Maybe there are some browser out there, which can interpret `{ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 }`. But it is not valid syntax (see MDN docs). With FF 69 I get `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '='`. You can however write `console.log({ a: y = 1 } = { b: 2 })`, because now the engine can be sure, that the function argument is an expression and not a block (sequence of statements). Have a look at [expressions vs statement](https://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html).

Comment: You're right, firefox does throw an error. So, probably a bug in V8

Comment: @adiga thanks for your hint anyway, there seems to be more clarification demand. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you all for the effort you put in explaining this very little code snippet. Several answers and comments are helpful, and this one is the most helpful with all its links to different key aspects of JS: blocks, expressions, statements… I indeed tried this code in a browser console; Chrome 76 to be precise. Running it in a `node` console yields the same results, but running it in Firefox 69 outputs a SyntaxError for both lines. I expect I'll come back very often to the several answers and links in the future 

Comment: btw: tried it with Chrome - you are right, it works there. As explained earlier, its not valid JS syntax. I could imagine, Chrome does some intelligent thing, and auto wraps the code in an expression context. But I am not sure.

Comment: @bartocc concerning chrome/node differences: Have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you run it. If this thing is on the top level, as in

```
{ a: 1 } = { b: 2 }
```

the error is "unexpected =", because `{a:1}` is a block, not an object (see e.g. [Differentiate a block from an object initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522426/differentiate-a-block-from-an-object-initializer)).

If used as an expression

```
({ a: 1 } = { b: 2 })
```

the error (in V8 at least) is "Invalid destructuring assignment target".

This:

```
let { a: 1 } = { b: 2 };
```

yields "Unexpected number", although it's the same error as in the above: you cannot have a variable named "1".

Finally, if you run this in the console, the result in generally unpredictable, because consoles try to be "helpful" and do weird things with evaluated code.

Comment: It would be nice to add a short explanation on why the first example does work as a block.

Comment: @Nit: yep, added a link

Answer (score 1):

They are different because in `{ a: y } =`, `y` is a value container that can be assigned to (and is parsed as such because the expression as you wrote it is parsed as a destructuring expression). `1` is a value and can't be assigned to. So it doesn't make for a valid destructuring expression. `{ a: y = 1 } =` does not mean `{ a: ( y = 1 ) } =` but `y = 1; { a: y } =`. Again, it's special destructuring semantics that may run counter-intuitively to usual significance of operators. The dangers of mixing functional and imperative language paradigms :)